# Divide an Image into Checkboards type (m xn ) and for each alternate sub-block of the image should be grayscale using C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, wpfdatagrid

I am a beginner to C# WPF, I would like to divide an color image into m x n Sub blocks and suppose I divide an image into 4 x 4 blocks then if Sub-block(1,1) is color, then (1,2) should be in grayscale, next (1,3) again in color. So the entire block of image should alternate between color and grayscale. I am not so good at WPF, so can anyone guide me on how to divide an image into sub- blocks and how to alternate the colors between each sub-block. 
What I have done till now is that I have written the below code in my MainWindow.xaml file.
My idea was to insert an Image into the Main Window, Split it into Grids using RowDefinition/ColumnDefinition or using gridSplitter. But I am not able to accomplish what i wanted. can anyone help me on this? Advance Thanks.

```
 <Window x:Class="Enter_your_name.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Image Source="D:/training/black.png" >

        </Image> 
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
       </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>  
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: nice challenge, I'll give it a try. if I am not wrong you want to create mosaic tiles for the given image in alternating color and b/w. correct me if I miss something

Comment: @pushpraj- Yeah you are exactly right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could overlay the original and gray-scale version of the image (i.e. use two images) and make sure the gray-scale version is the top one. Then apply a checkerboard brush as an opacity mask to the gray-scale version. This results in a pattern of "checkerboard holes" that let the original image shine through.

Here is an example:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication21.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <BitmapImage x:Key="originalImage"  DecodePixelWidth="200" UriSource="c:\temp\test_picture.jpg"/>
        <FormatConvertedBitmap x:Key="grayScaleImage"
                Source="{StaticResource originalImage}" 
                DestinationFormat="Gray32Float"></FormatConvertedBitmap>
        <DrawingBrush x:Key="checkerboardBrush" Stretch="UniformToFill" TileMode="Tile" Viewport="0,0,0.5,0.5" ViewportUnits="RelativeToBoundingBox">
            <DrawingBrush.Drawing>
                <DrawingGroup>
                    <GeometryDrawing Brush="#00FFFFFF">
                        <GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                            <RectangleGeometry Rect="0,0,2,2" />
                        </GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                    </GeometryDrawing>
                    <GeometryDrawing Brush="#FF000000">
                        <GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                            <GeometryGroup>
                                <RectangleGeometry Rect="0,0,1,1" />
                                <RectangleGeometry Rect="1,1,1,1" />
                            </GeometryGroup>
                        </GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                    </GeometryDrawing>
                </DrawingGroup>
            </DrawingBrush.Drawing>
        </DrawingBrush>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Image Source="{StaticResource originalImage}" Panel.ZIndex="1"/>
        <Image Source="{StaticResource grayScaleImage}" Panel.ZIndex="2" OpacityMask="{StaticResource checkerboardBrush}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

[image: screen shot]

In order to change the NxM pattern, you need to tweak the `Viewport` property of the `DrawingBrush`.

Comment: @fmunkert- Thanks a lot. I could do that easily with ur snippet. But How am i supposed to use the same effects for images with  just Vertical or Horizontal Lines.

Comment: nice trick! btw is it also possible to make the tiles fit without calculating?

Comment: @pushpraj: I have adapted my sample such that it needs less calculations and that the tiles fit exactly. `Viewport="0,0,0.5,0.5"` means 4x4 tiles, `Viewport="0,0,.25,.25"` means 8x8 tiles, and so on. Or generally, `0,0,x,y` means 2/x by 2/y tiles.

Comment: @Jonas: Do you mean that you want just vertical or horizontal lines instead of a checkerboard pattern? If yes, then use a `DrawingGroup` which draws a vertical or horizontal line.